# How to dynamically display sum of selected row data on Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to dynamically display the sum of selected column data through `SelectionModel` on the selected rows below my table. The data displayed should change when I select/deselected the rows.

I thought `ngOnInit()` would allow me to achieve that, however the sum of selected column data is not changing.

```
totalWeight = 0;

  ngOnInit(): void{
    this.selection.selected.forEach((element) => {
      this.totalWeight += element.weight;
    });
  }
```

Here's the [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qvmwya) on Stackblitz.

Comment: That's because that code is only executed **once** in that lifecycle hook. You should use the `changed` event such that that portion of your code will be executed each time the selection is modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `changed` event of the `SelectionModel` API which returns a `SelectionChange` event emitted when the selection is changed, instead of the `selected` variable of the `SelectionModel` API.

The `SelectionChange` interface has the following properties (taken from the source code):

```js
/**
 * Event emitted when the value of a MatSelectionModel has changed.
 * @docs-private
 */
export interface SelectionChange<T> {
  /** Model that dispatched the event. */
  source: SelectionModel<T>;
  /** Options that were added to the model. */
  added: T[];
  /** Options that were removed from the model. */
  removed: T[];
}
```

You can then add or remove the weight from the `totalWeight` property as follows:

```js
totalWeight = 0;

ngOnInit(): void{
  this.selection.changed.subscribe(change => {
      console.log('Added items:', change.added);
      console.log('Removed items:', change.removed);
      console.log('Source selection model:', change.source);
      change.added.forEach(element => {
          this.totalWeight += element.weight;
      })
      change.removed.forEach(element => {
          this.totalWeight -= element.weight;
      })
  });
}
```

[Updated demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qvmwya-pz8ywm?file=app/table-selection-example.ts)

Comment: I can't open your updated demo and did you make any changes to the html?? I'm using ```{{totalWeight}}```, the changes are being displayed side by side instead of the sum of weight (e.g. 2.005.00 instead of 7.00 as the sum)

Comment: Oops - that's because I've made it private. I've just toggled the setting.

Answer (score 2):

You need to calculate the total each time when the checkedbox value is changed,

```
 calculate(row?: PeriodicElement)
  {
    this.totalWeight = 0;
    this.selection.selected.forEach((element) => {
      this.totalWeight += element.weight;
    });
  }
```

[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qvmwya-zardux?file=app/table-selection-example.ts)

Comment: I'm using ```{{totalWeight}}``` in the html file, the changes are being displayed side by side instead of the sum of weight (e.g. if I select rows with weight 2.00 and 5.00, it's showing 2.005.00 instead of 7.00 as the sum). Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Although people have already explained what the real problem was and the question has already been answered, I want to show you how you can do this with a reactive approach:

**TS**:

```
readonly totalWeights$ = this.selection.changed.pipe(
  map(() => this.selection.selected.reduce((acc, value) => acc + value.weight, 0)),
  startWith(0)
);
```

**HTML**:

```
<p>Total selected weight: {{ totalWeights$ | async }}</p>
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qvmwya-3vlysn)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, define a handler to calculate  sum of the each weight(named **changeEvent**):

```
<mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null;changeEvent(row)"
                [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"
                [aria-label]="checkboxLabel(row)">
```

Then in your ts using `reduce` you can do:

```
public changeEvent(row?: PeriodicElement){
  this.totalWeight = 0;
  this.totalWeight = this.selection.selected.reduce((prev, cur)=>{
   return prev + cur.weight;
  }, 0);
}
```